# Argument for designing an ocean monitoring network based on satellite-derived chlorophyll-a concentration?

Tags: oceanography, satellites, in-situ-measurements

The idea is to design an integrated marine monitoring network by surveying in parallel the chlorophyll-a and the other oceanography parameters, which are either trophically related with the concentration of chlorophyll-a (e.g. nutrients, zooplankton) or topically-related (having the same origin), e.g. nutrients and contaminants have the same land-based point sources of pollution.

The simplest approach is to place the sampling stations at equal distance from the land-based sources of pollution to detect of the pressure from pollution with nutrients and contaminants and its effect on the marine ecosystem. This approach is supported by the fact that the water column parameters have relatively homogeneous distribution, because of the water mixing.

The question is: is there an argument for applying a more sophisticated approach of using the analysis average multi-annual satellite-derived spatial change in the concentration of chlorophyll-a for choosing a sampling location of the monitoring network? And if it is, what method can be used to place the sampling stations (Besides the [ArcGIS Sampling Network Design Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/helmain/10.1/index.html#//00300000000p000000%29))?

Comment: @daniel.neumann - is there a site that gives ocean chlorophyll images - the JAXA site just does not have updated images ?

Comment: Did I post a comment here a now it is gone ... ? Whatever ... . There is the Ocean Colour Climate Change Initiative ([OC CCI](http://www.esa-oceancolour-cci.org/)), which provides satellite derived chl-a data [as pictures](https://www.oceancolour.org/browser/) and as netCDF data. There is also a [webGIS](https://www.oceancolour.org/portal/). In future, chl-a data obtained by [Sentinel-3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-3A) (when fully validated) will be available from the [Marine Service](http://marine.copernicus.eu/) of the EU Copernicus Programme.